# Dynamically updating an asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

How could you update asp.net application from a central location. I would like to publish the final updates to a central location and have all the sites download latest updates from that central location.

Its like having ur wordpress site getting the latest version for word press ur yahoo asking users to migrate to the latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tool you buy, or try to write your own scripts. Writing them for yourself is not that hard.

From tools I know of [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) or [Redgate Deployment Manager](http://www.red-gate.com/delivery/deployment-manager/) (RedGate bought Octopus' sources and now sells as it's own project with some modifications/additional features). With those tools you install their agent on target servers to be able to deploy new versions of your web sites to those servers. Octopus works in both push and pull model. I don't know about Deployment Manager.

In my work I publish using self written scripts that are configured as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) jobs. One click and new version is installed. This is a "push" update.

Remember that in order to update the web site without users noticing (no technical break) you need at least two servers and load balancer and a shared state service. Before deployment you need to reconfigure Load Balancer so that it routes all requests to one server. Then you update that server. Now reconfigure Load Balancer so that it routes all requests to the updated server, and update the other one. After you update all servers reconfigure Load Balancer again so requests are routed to all servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main approaches:

The first is to "push" the updates, such that when you upload a new release it will contact each website (such as sending a request to a trigger URI) causing each site to download-and-install the update you've provided. This would require your central update site to maintain a database of sites to inform about an update.

The second is to have the site's code include a check (on a separate thread so it doesn't block any page requests) that it hasn't been `n` days since it last checked for an update, and if so, to check with your central server for an update, and if applicable, download and isntall it. This approach means that your central server does not need to be aware of consuming sites, only vice-versa.

Comment: hi dai, can you provide some usefull links, its helps me to understand well

Comment: but how do i write such a code. is there such a feature in .net like it is in desktop application.
im not sure how to write a code to replace every folder and file in the asp.net directory. 
A small code sample will help

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have done same thing. But in my approach application does not ask user to download the latest version. It directly download the latest version. What I have done :

1. Create a webservice in your application. Which will receive data and directly update the database or any other part of your project.

2.Then you have to create a windows application which will be installed on your server.
And it consume the webservice of your application in client machine. Now just write a scheduler in your win app that will start every night or whatever you want. Whenever it will start, it call all the services and send them the updated data. And your service will receive this and update the application.

Let me know, it helps or not

Comment: thanks but its on a shared host. I'll experiment with extracting zip files of the project but it feels unsafe since there can be a man in the middle attack. its not just updating its replacing all meaning my entire logic or most of it is flown over the wire.
Scratching my head